# CURL request to Python as command line

Tags: python, curl, subprocess, pycurl

Currently, I'm trying to convert CURL request to Python script.

```
curl $(curl -u username:password -s https://api.example.com/v1.1/reports/11111?fields=download | jq ".report.download" -r) > "C:\sample.zip"
```

I have tried pycurl, with no success, due to knowledge limitation.

As a solution, I have found, that it is possible to run commands through python.
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=112351

```
import os
os.system("curl -K.........")
```

And other solution ( based on the search more common) using subprocess

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(['command', 'argument'])
```

Currently, I'm not sure where to move and how to adapt this solution to my sitionation.

```
import os

os.system("curl $(curl -u username:password -s https://api.example.com/v1.1/reports/11111?fields=download | jq '.report.download' -r) > 'C:\sample.zip'")

'curl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
255
```

**P.S. - Update v1**

Any suggestion?

```
import requests

response = requests.get('https://api.example.com/v1.1/reports/11111?fields=download | jq ".report.download" -r', auth=('username', 'password'))
```

This work without "`| jq ".report.download`" this part, but this is the main part which gives at the end only link to download the file.

ANy way around it?

Comment: `requests` module should help you

Comment: `curl` executable is not in `PATH` environment variable, Try to add  `curl` to path or install it from `apt` using `apt-get install curl`

Comment: @Rakesh have updated ( please have a look )

Comment: @sriharsha_bhat that have potential, but issue appear when I try to use JQ.

Comment: @Rakesh Look, the request does work, BUT jq section after the pipe do not work which gives me instead of full JSON just the content of it, any suggestions???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error `'curl' is not recognized as an internal or external command` means that python couldn't find the location where curl is installed. If you have already installed curl, try giving the full path to where `curl` is installed. For example, if curl.exe is located in C:\System32, the try

```
import os

os.system("C:\System32\curl $(curl -u username:password -s https://api.example.com/v1.1/reports/11111?fields=download | jq '.report.download' -r) > 'C:\sample.zip'")
```

But thats definitely not pythonic way of doing things. I would instead suggest to use `requests` module.
You need to invoke requests module twice for this, first to download the json content from `https://api.example.com/v1.1/reports/11111?fields=download`, get a new url pointed by`report.download` and then invoke requests again to download data from the new url.

Something along these lines should get you going

```
import requests

url        = 'https://api.example.com/v1.1/reports/11111'
response   = requests.get(url, params=(('fields', 'download'),),
                          auth=('username', 'password'))

report_url = response.json()['report']['download']
data = requests.get(report_url).content

with open('C:\sample.zip', 'w') as f:
    f.write(data)
```

Comment: Thank you for this help, I'm really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this site to convert the actual curl part of your command to something that works with requests: https://curl.trillworks.com/

From there, just use the `.json()` method of the request object to do whatever processing you need to be doing.

Finally, can save like so:

```
import json
with open('C:\sample.zip', 'r') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
```

Comment: This is the website which I have used for other parts to convert, but this specific part, I could not manage to convert yet.